# Generate XML from a class with JAVA

Tags: java, xml

I asked this question before:

[Generate XML from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281703/generate-xml-from-a-class)

I want to do this with Java.

Is it possible to do the same with Java via attributes?

or is there a framework i can use for this purpose as well.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736343/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-java-object-to-xml-with-open-source-apis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org) will allow you to represent any class as an XML. You can check [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) for an example.

Comment: +1 Using XStream would be the simplest and easiest on this occassion.

Comment: One of the first dependencies I add to a new project. Even without any XML need: very useful for debugging !

Comment: Cool. That IS a really simple solution.  I've never read about xstream until now.

Comment: @Jakrabbit: It is usually very simple and straightforward to use. If I am not mistaken XML generation can be controlled, to a certain extent, through the use of annotations.

Comment: @DarthVader - For a JAXB (JSR-222)/XStream comparison see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html.  Note I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead.

Answer (score 5):

[JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) could be what you want.  It's fairly common.  You just add some annotations to your properties and any instance of that class can be serialized/deserialized to XML.

Comment: +1 for JAXB (JSR-222).  JAXB implementations (Metro, MOXy, etc) do not require any annotations, they are only needed to customize the default XML representation:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

Answer (score 0):

I prefer XStream, but there is also [Castor XML](http://castor.org/xml-framework.html)